# MYSQL conditional WHERE clause. Ignore if row doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with the following structure:

```
    TABLE 1
minutes | date

    TABLE 2
hours | date
```

And what I want is it to select minutes from table1, hours from table2, where the dates match up. The only problem is there isn't always an entry in table2 that matches up with table1, and in that case I only want to select the data from table1. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

you should use a LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT t1.minutes, t2.hours FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.date = t2.date
```

Comment: And if there is no occurrence where t1.date = t2.date it will still return something?

Comment: it will return all the rows of the table t1